# Merge two array of objects together

Tags: javascript

I have two array of object and i would like to merge them together so i can map them and display the data in the frontend.

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1, symbol: "France", position: "South"},{id: 2, symbol: "Sweden", city: "Malmo"}]

const arr2 = [{id: 1, symbol: "USA", city: "Los angeles"},{id: 2, symbol: "France", city: "Paris"}]
```

Expected output:

```
const arr3 =[{id: 1, symbol: "France", city: "Paris", position: "South"}, {id: 1, symbol: "USA", city: "Los angeles"} ]
```

Here is my solution but i'm not getting the output that i want.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, symbol: "France", position: "South"},{id: 2, symbol: "Sweden", city: "Malmo"}]
const arr2 = [{id: 1, symbol: "USA", city: "Los angeles"},{id: 2, symbol: "France", city: "Paris"}]

const countries = arr1.map((item, i) => {
  return Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]);
});

console.log(countries)
```

Comment: you can't use an index from the first array to select an element from the 2nd one if you want to match themby symbol field

Comment: What's supposed to happen to those Objects with the symbol of "USA" and "Sweden"?

Comment: Have them in the new array of object

Answer (score 0):

you can use `concat` like this to merge two array

```js
    const arr1 = [{id: 1, symbol: "France", position: "South"},{id: 2, symbol: "Sweden", city: "Malmo"}]
    const arr2 = [{id: 1, symbol: "USA", city: "Los angeles"},{id: 2, symbol: "France", city: "Paris"}]
    
    const countries = arr1.concat(arr2)
    console.log(countries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not possible as per your question.
my answer may be helpful for you if you are looking something like this

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, symbol: "France", position: "South"},{id: 2, symbol: "Sweden", city: "Malmo"}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, symbol: "USA", city: "Los angeles"},{id: 2, symbol: "France", city: "Paris"}];
const arr3 = [...arr1,...arr2];
console.log(arr3);
```